# HAproxy backend based on hostname?

Tags: haproxy, port, hostname, backend

I have a question about using hostnames in a haproxy backend.
We have some software that runs it's own webserver. The internal url is:
192.168.x.xxx:82/Production/ I want it to be accessible from the internet. Normally not a problem. I've done this with other systems. I've configured everything the same as I did with other internal sites. Only problem is configuring the backend because after the port number there is a /production to enter the site. I've configured it like this in haproxy but it doesn't work, does anybody know how to make this work?

backend system
    mode http
    option httpchk 
    server system-01 192.168.x.xxx:82/Production/ check

Comment: Please share your configuration.